# r geom_map fails with GeoJSON map simplified with gSimplify

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm constructing world maps with countries color-filled with the (continuous) value depending on a column in a data frame called `temp.sp`. I want to put several of these maps in a graph. I construct each map using `ggplot` with `geom_map` and then construct and display the graphs using `multiplot()` which uses `grid` code.

I'm using a GeoJSON map (`world <- readOGR(dsn = "ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")`). The resulting `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` is 4.1 Mb and the dataframe that results from `worldMap <- broom::tidy(world, region = "iso_a3")` has 93391 rows. So when I run multiplot with 4 plot files, it takes a long time.

I thought that I could speed up the printing by simplifying the world map with `gSimplify` using code like `world.simp <- gSimplify(world, tol = .1, topologyPreserve = TRUE)`. The resulting data frame, `worldMap.simp` only has 27033 rows but when I use this map I get the error message `Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`.

The error message is generated when I run this code with worldMap.simp. When I use worldMap I have no problems.

`gg <- ggplot(temp.sp, aes(map_id = id)) 
 gg <- gg + geom_map(aes(fill = temp.sp$value), map = worldMap.simp, color = "white")`.

I tried converting temp.sp$value to factor but it made no difference.

To summarize, using a gSimplified map causes the displaying of a graph produced with ggplot and geom_map to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to figure out what was going wrong with gSimplify, I found and downloaded a lower resolution map from http://geojson.xyz. The one I'm currently using is
https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geojson

Note that it has a similar filename, but with 110m instead of 50m.